# What is meant by 'down and out'

Tags: idioms

I know it's an idiom and it has two and three meanings .But here I heard this as ' when I feel down and out before the scene , I have two bananas and I feel good.' So what is exact meaning here?

Comment: I think it means to be *unhappy*, because from what I know, *banana* is a happy fruit :)

Comment: Where did you hear that?  Can you provide more context?

Comment: I don't think this "idiom" has any real currency in conversational English today. I only know it from Orwell's [*Down and Out in Paris and London*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_and_Out_in_Paris_and_London) and a few [quirky film titles](http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=down+and+out&s=all). For your context, forget the ***and out*** bit, and say *When I feel down [I do such-and-such to lighten my mood].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I dunno - as you point out, it's been used in film titles repeatedly over the last 25 years or so, not to mention book titles like [Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom](http://podiobooks.com/title/down-and-out-in-the-magic-kingdom/) or [Down and Out in America: The Origins of Homelessness](https://books.google.com/books?id=iNonAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22down+and+out+in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWo6eu75fSAhVlrVQKHYH4D7IQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22down%20and%20out%20in%22&f=false).  I would say it's reasonably current.

Comment: @stangdon: I would say it is reasonably current, but not in a meaning that fits the original questions. To me it means more or less the same as "on the street".

Comment: @ColinFine - Perhaps true.  It's hard for me to tell what's intended in the original question, given the lack of much context.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole) or self-dramatization as used there. The speaker doesn't mean he's literally "down and out" (destitute and suffering), but merely feeling flat, listless, lacking energy.

It is quite common for people to use language with heightened, intensified expressions to express quite ordinary conditions. Example:

> A. How are you today?
>   B. I'm just dead. I stayed up way too late last night. I could do that kind of thing in college, but now that I'm over 30 it just kills me.

Obviously **B** isn't really dead, or he wouldn't be talking. He's just being dramatic to bring home a point.

Answer (score 1):

[LINK OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/down_and_out)

> > ADJECTIVE
> >
> > 1(of a person) without money, a job, or a place to live; destitute. ‘a
> >     novel about being down and out in London’
>
> Synonyms  2(of a boxer) knocked down and unable to continue fighting.
>
> > 2.1 (of a competitor) facing certain defeat. ‘behind, away from home, and down to 14 men, Kelso ought to have been down and out, but
> >     Jeffrey
> >     rallied his men’

Out of money, without a home...

It could be referring to the second definition, a knockout in a boxing ring.

[LINK](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Down-And-Out.html) This site  says that the origin is from the boxing ring. This also is what I think.

In your sample, I think it is used badly. I believe the writer means that when they feel tired and less than happy and healthy, that bananas are a good pick me up.

In writing, we often see writers use literary license as a way of making the writing stand out or be more interesting. This sample, in my own opinion, fell short of the mark.